# Quarkus native compilation fails after aws sdk dependency (netty-logging related?)

Tags: quarkus, graalvm-native-image, quarkus-native

I'm building a native Quarkus app with "-Dnative -Dquarkus.native.container-build=true" but after including the software.amazon.awssdk:secretsmanager:2.20.136 and the buddies it pulls in I get a

```
Caused by: com.oracle.graal.pointsto.constraints.UnresolvedElementException: Discovered unresolved type during parsing: io.netty.util.internal.logging.Log4J2Logger. This error is reported at image build time because class io.netty.util.internal.logging.Log4J2LoggerFactory is registered for linking at image build time by command line
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.phases.SharedGraphBuilderPhase$SharedBytecodeParser.reportUnresolvedElement(SharedGraphBuilderPhase.java:521)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.phases.SharedGraphBuilderPhase$SharedBytecodeParser.reportUnresolvedElement(SharedGraphBuilderPhase.java:515)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.phases.SharedGraphBuilderPhase$SharedBytecodeParser.handleUnresolvedType(SharedGraphBuilderPhase.java:407)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.phases.SharedGraphBuilderPhase$SharedBytecodeParser.handleUnresolvedNewInstance(SharedGraphBuilderPhase.java:263)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.genNewInstance(BytecodeParser.java:4531)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.genNewInstance(BytecodeParser.java:4524)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.processBytecode(BytecodeParser.java:5334)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.iterateBytecodesForBlock(BytecodeParser.java:3406)
    ... 43 more
```

I saw a few similar reports but resolving those issues appear to be... non-trivial. Any pointers on this specific aws-sdk tree?

Update: adding quarkus-netty as suggested by @geoand yields another exception:

```
Caused by: com.oracle.graal.pointsto.constraints.UnresolvedElementException: Discovered unresolved type during parsing: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory. This error is reported at image build time because class org.apache.http.conn.util.PublicSuffixMatcherLoader is registered for linking at image build time by command line
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.phases.SharedGraphBuilderPhase$SharedBytecodeParser.reportUnresolvedElement(SharedGraphBuilderPhase.java:521)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.phases.SharedGraphBuilderPhase$SharedBytecodeParser.reportUnresolvedElement(SharedGraphBuilderPhase.java:515)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.phases.SharedGraphBuilderPhase$SharedBytecodeParser.handleUnresolvedType(SharedGraphBuilderPhase.java:407)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.phases.SharedGraphBuilderPhase$SharedBytecodeParser.handleUnresolvedMethod(SharedGraphBuilderPhase.java:435)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.phases.SharedGraphBuilderPhase$SharedBytecodeParser.handleUnresolvedInvoke(SharedGraphBuilderPhase.java:338)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.genInvokeStatic(BytecodeParser.java:1680)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.genInvokeStatic(BytecodeParser.java:1655)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.processBytecode(BytecodeParser.java:5331)
    at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.iterateBytecodesForBlock(BytecodeParser.java:3406)
    ... 42 more
```

also adding commons-logging and log4j gives

> Error: Detected an instance of Random/SplittableRandom class in the image heap...
>
> Detailed message:
> Trace: Object was reached by
> trying to constant fold static field org.apache.http.impl.auth.NTLMEngineImpl.RND_GEN
> at org.apache.http.impl.auth.NTLMEngineImpl.access$000(NTLMEngineImpl.java:51)
> parsing method org.apache.http.impl.auth.NTLMEngineImpl.access$000(NTLMEngineImpl.java:51) reachable via the parsing context
> at static root method.(Unknown Source)

One would think that everyone doing SDK operations from a AWS lambda in Quarkus native would run into this(?)

Thanks in advance,
Nik

Comment: Can you try adding `quarkus-netty` to the application?

Comment: "Progress!" as we say in the business when it breaks in a new place ;-)

Caused by: com.oracle.graal.pointsto.constraints.UnresolvedElementException: Discovered unresolved type during parsing: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory. This error is reported at image build time because class org.apache.http.conn.util.PublicSuffixMatcherLoader is registered for linking at image build time by command line

Comment: Hm... Actually taking a step back, what exactly are you trying to use from the AWS SDK?

Comment: The secrets manager for accessing a secret based on an ARN passed in through the environment. Can be reproduced just by generating a Quarkus project from the lambda archetype and adding the 2.x security manager dependency and building it as native

Comment: Doesn't [this](https://docs.quarkiverse.io/quarkus-amazon-services/dev/amazon-secretsmanager.html) extension already provide that capability?

Comment: Ah! Thanks, missed that one.

Comment: You are welcome! Is everything working in that case?

Comment: Yes, up and running again!